# What happen if I try to evaluate non-existing property of entries?(Datastore, Python)

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am making a web app using GAE datastore and need to update model schema. Currently, I have model like this.

```
class Group(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    div = db.StringProperty()
```

But I want to add mid property with default value.

```
class Group(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    div = db.StringProperty()
    mid = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

I understand this won't update existing entries reading through this article. 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema

It is ok for me existing entries stay without mid property because I will not use this property for query. But I need to use this to assert the situation. If I retrieved all the entries from datastore and evaluate mid property, does this result in AttributeError or something?

```
groups = [e for e in Group.all()]
for group in groups:
    if group.mid == 3:
        dosomething...
```

If attribute error will happen, is there any to avoid the error? I am a bit expecting this might not result in error since I set a default value....

Comment: Updates: I did some experiments on this and it seems that default value will be applied when the entry doesn't have mid.Of course, it will not change the data itself but I didn't encounter Attribute error...

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
groups = [e for e in Group.all()]
for group in groups:
    try:
        if group.mid == 3:
            #do_your_thing...
    except: #or except AttributeError
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping AttributeError will not happen but seems like it will... I think your idea is clear and great. Can I also avoid the error to check attribute existence using hasattr(group, 'mid') ? So the code will be like this in the loop. `if  hasattr(group, 'mid') and group.mid`